# Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to get this to work but to no avail, can someone help?

```
number = 0
statement = "i will go there",number,"times"
for number in statement:
    if number < 5:
        print (statement)
number += 1
```

What I am trying to do here is to build a general statement first (I will go there number times). I want to change the 'number' inside this statement to 0,1,2,3,4,5 and eventually it prints:

```
i will go there 0 times
i will go there 1 times
i will go there 2 times
i will go there 3 times
i will go there 4 times
i will go there 5 times
```

But i am getting an error code of:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Thanks for all the feedback, guys. You see, I am using this example to understand another set of code which I am working on. The code is as below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


chrome_path = r"C:\Users\lnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Selenium Chrome 
Driver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys(input('What do you want to search?'))
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)

## Prints info seen on Page 1 of search result
##result = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('st')
##for post in result:
##    print (post.text)


## Prints the info seen on Page 2 of search result, video suggested using a FOR loop to automatically scrape and print info from other page
##driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a').click()
##result2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('st')
##for post in result2:
##    print (post.text)

x = 1

new_page ="""driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@id="nav"]/tbody/tr/td[{}]/a').click()""" 

while (x<6):
    exec(new_page.format(x))
    result3 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('st')
    for post in result3:
        print (post.text)
    x +=1
```

I get this idea from watching this Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O--WVte1WhU

The idea is to scrape the info seen on a google search result webpage (class name:'st'), but i want to scrape until, say page 5 of the google search result. The video suggested using a For loop to automatically scrape and print info from other pages. I managed to change the page number by using .format(x) as suggested from the answer by 'molbdnilo'. However, the new page (stored in new_page) is being stored as a list, therefore it cannot be executed. The error message i got is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I tried to do a little troubleshooting with the below code:

```
x = 1

new_page = """print('dog{}')"""

while (x<6):
    exec(new_page.format(x))
    x +=1
```

And it behaved very well by printing:
dog1
dog2
dog3
dog4
dog5
I don'd understand why it couldn't work in my scraping code. The new_page is supposed to loop over 1-6 while changing the page number and executing it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You are using the same variable for both( number=0) and (for number in statement). So when if number < 5 is executed, number holds the substring from statement!

Comment: Also you need to indent the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

`number in statement` does not mean "the variable 'number' that I used when I created 'statement'".

`for number in statement` loops over the elements of `statements`, and on each iteration `number` refers to that element.

Open your interpreter and look at what you're making.

```
>>> number = 0
>>> statement = "i will go there",number,"times"
>>> statement
('i will go there', 0, 'times')
```

So `statement` is a tuple with tree elements.
The second element holds the value that `number` had when you created it.

```
>>> number = 1000
>>> statement
('i will go there', 0, 'times')
```

Notice that the second element of `statement` didn't change.

```
>>> for number in statement: print 'number is', number
...
number is i will go there
number is 0
number is times
```

And this loops over the elements of `statement`.

To accomplish what you want, create a string inside the loop.
If you want to have a general statement that you put a number in later, use `format`.

Something like this:

```
statement = "i will go there {} times"
for number in range(1,6):
    print statement.format(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print something like.

```
I will go there 0 times
I will go there 1 times
I will go there 2 times


In[126]: for n in range(5):
    ...:      print('I will go there ' + str(n) + ' times')
    ...:
I will go there 0 times
I will go there 1 times
I will go there 2 times
I will go there 3 times
I will go there 4 times
```

Tell me if this is the answer you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in range(5):
    print("i will go there {} times".format(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
statement = "i will go there {} times"
for number in range(6):
    print (statement.format(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
number = 5
statement = "i will go there "

for i in range(10):
  if i <= number:
      print(statement + str(i) + " time")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to get the whole code to work. Working code as below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


chrome_path = r"C:\Users\lnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Selenium Chrome 
Driver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys(input('What do you want to search?'))
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)


result = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('st')
for post in result:
    print (post.text)

for x in range (3,6):
    new_page = repr('//*[@id="nav"]/tbody/tr/td[{}]/a').format(x)
    data = [exec('driver.find_element_by_xpath('+new_page+').click()')]
    for i in data:
        result3 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('st')
        for post in result3:
            print (post.text)


driver.quit()
```

When the Youtube video author said For loop to automate the page, i should have just automated only the Xpath portion. Silly me...took me so long to realise this.

PS:Newbie here, i've only picked up Python for 1 month.